# update table with another table taking columns names the second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 1 table that I want to update with another table. The issue is that the column name to update is contained in the resulting select

I have tried many different ways, going through the cases in stackoverflow but not success.

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA (
  TA int
  , FM int
  , YTM int
  , YTW int
  , FFH int
  , TCWH int
  , BRH int
  , DH int
  , DV int
  , BN int
  , PP int
);

select * from #tableA;

CREATE TABLE #TableB (
  footnote VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , row_ref int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TableB (footnote, row_ref)
  VALUES ('TA', 1),
       ('FFH', 2),
       ('BRH', 7);
```

And the idea is to update #tableA in columns TA, FFH and BRH (defined in #TableB) with values from #tableB

Comment: So you're expecting just a single row to be inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it provided you want one row in #tableA for each row in #tableB.

```
INSERT INTO #tableA
(TA, FM, YTM, YTW, FFH, TCWH, BRH, DH, DV, BN, PP)
SELECT IIF(footnote = 'TA', row_ref, NULL)   AS TA
     , IIF(footnote = 'FM', row_ref, NULL)   AS FM
     , IIF(footnote = 'YTM', row_ref, NULL)  AS YTM
     , IIF(footnote = 'YTW', row_ref, NULL)  AS YTW
     , IIF(footnote = 'FFH', row_ref, NULL)  AS FFH
     , IIF(footnote = 'TCWH', row_ref, NULL) AS TCWH
     , IIF(footnote = 'BRH', row_ref, NULL)  AS BRH
     , IIF(footnote = 'DH', row_ref, NULL)   AS DH
     , IIF(footnote = 'DV', row_ref, NULL)   AS DV
     , IIF(footnote = 'BN', row_ref, NULL)   AS BN
     , IIF(footnote = 'PP', row_ref, NULL)   AS PP
FROM   #TableB;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into #tableA ([TA],[FFH],[BRH])
select [TA],[FFH],[BRH]
from #TableB
pivot (max(row_ref) for footnote in ([TA],[FFH],[BRH])) pvt
```